# (PHP) Can you use the outcome of an if statement in a calculation?

Tags: php, if-statement

So I have two different prices per product in my database table. One is the "sale_price" and the other is the usual "price" of the product. I have made it so that if the "sale" column is set to "yes" in the database, then it will display the sale price of the product and vice-versa.

Here is my code that calculates the total price of the product by multiplying the quantity by the price of the product. You'll see that `if` `$cart[sale']` is equal to 'yes' then it will create a variable called `$tot`: this will multiply `$cart['sale_price']` of the product by `$cart['quantity]` `else` it will multiply the `$cart['price']` by `$cart['quantity]`. This will display the total price PER PRODUCT...

```
<?php if($cartprod['salec'] == "yes"){

    $tot = number_format($cartprod['list_price'] * $cartprod['quantity'],2);

}else{

    $tot = number_format($cartprod['price'] *  $cartprod['quantity'],2);

}?>
```

... I want to display the SUM of all of the totals in the cart but I can't seem to achieve it. Can anybody lead me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, highly suggested to use `boolean` type instead of `string`! For example, `sale` can be boolean and save `true` and `false`, instead of `yes` and `no`.

If you want to calculate the sum of your basket, its easily can be done by something like this:

```
<?php

$sum = 0;
foreach ($products as $product) {
    $total = 0;

    if ($product['sale'] === 'yes') {
        $total = $product['sale_price'];
    } else {
        $total = $product['price'];
    }

    $total *= $product['quantity'];
    $sum += $total;
}

echo number_format($sum, 2);
```

I just used your sample codes logic, it depends on yourself how you want to implement it in your project...

Answer (score 0):

Try this snippet, it should work

```
        $tot=0;

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM yourDB order by  SomeID ASC";
        $resulto = mysqli_query($conn,$sql) or die (mysqli_error());

        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($resulto)){

            $salec=$row['salec'];
            $list_price=$row['list_price'];
            $price=$row['price'];
            $quantiry=$row['quantity'];

            if($salec=="Yes"){
                $tot .= number_format(($list_price * $quantity), 2);
            }else{
                $tot .= number_format(($price * $quantity), 2);
            }
        }
```